# QuickBase jQuery/Ajax call puzzler

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, quickbase

I have puzzled over this QuickBase jQuery/Ajax problem for the better part of two days. Consider this jquery code running inside $(function()...:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://www.quickbase.com/db/<mydbid>", // <- returns error
                //url: "http://pfs.fedcap.com/testdata.xml",  // <- returns xml
                data: {
                    act:"API_DoQuery",
                    query:"{7.EX.235445}",
                    apptoken:"<myapptoken>"
                },
                dataType: "xml",
                error: function(xhr,status) {
                    alert("error");
                },
                success: function(xml) { 
                    alert("OK");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

As noted, the url pointing to QuickBase returns an error, but the url pointing to the xml file returns the xml as expected. But here's the kicker: the xml file (testdata.xml) was created by pointing my browser directly to the specified url: https://www.quickbase.com/db/<mydbid>?a=API_DoQuery&query={7.EX.235445}&apptoken=<myapptoken> and saving the results to testdata.xml. It seems to me the jquery ajax call SHOULD produce the same results as the testdata.xml file. But it does not.

The Firebug xml pane shows that the call when executed against the QuickBase site returns "XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: moz-nullprincipal:{3e0d38f1-0e36-4adb-965e-d0e7d68ab0cb} Line Number 1, Column 1:Reload the page to get source for: https://www.quickbase.com/db..."

What am I overlooking? Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, I've puzzled out that it is probably due to browsers' not allowing what is called cross-domain (or cross-site) ajax calls. This is not a problem with JSONP, but QuickBase does not respond to calls with JSON, only XML, apparently. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to write your own jQuery implementation of their API, you're much better off using their own javascript SDK. https://github.com/QuickbaseAdmirer/Quickbase-JavaScript-SDK

The important part that you are missing is the authentication call to get the 'ticket'. Supplying the application token is not enough to do a DoQuery call. You must authenticate and then use the ticket that is sent back to do any more API calls. For a url request, the ticket can be appended quite easily `&ticket=randomcharacters`. For a XML request, simply add `<ticket>randomcharacters</ticket>` to your XML request.

https://github.com/QuickbaseAdmirer/Quickbase-JavaScript-SDK has more information on how to use the Authenticate call.

Comment: I am unable to show/hide a processing loader image properly using this QuickBase JS SDK..any Ideas here for me?